# How would DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) work through an HTTP proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

Several articles [like this one](https://www.zdnet.com/article/dns-over-https-causes-more-problems-than-it-solves-experts-say/) claim that DoH bypasses enterprise policies.

However, in the case of an HTTP proxy, any web request will be sent to the proxy by the HTTP CONNECT method. The DNS resolution is done by the proxy server and not the personal computer which send the full URI in the CONNECT method.

How is DoH a concern for businesses in that case?

Answer (score 0):

*In general,* when a proxy is set up, browsers and other internet devices are set up to go to the proxy first and then go out.

For example, say you have a LAN with IP addresses `192.168.1.0/24` where you have a proxy sitting on `192.168.1.2`.

Your proxy is set up such that traffic must be negotiated first on the proxy before they hit the gateway.  In a non-DoH environment, your communication might go something like this:

1. Your browser asks: "What is the IP address of `stackoverflow.com`?"
2. The DNS server on your network says "It's `192.168.1.2`"
3. Your browser then sends the request to the proxy
4. The proxy then goes and asks the ISP "What is the IP address of `stackoverflow.com`?".
5. Once it has the real IP address, it negotiates the traffic between you, and stackoverflow, doing what proxies do.

With DoH, this is a bit different.  With DoH enabled and using Cloudflare as your DoH provider:

1. Your browser asks "What's the IP address of `cloudflare.com`?".
2. Your DNS server will respond `192.168.1.2` and will then negotiate the traffic between you and cloudflare.
3. Your browser asks "What is the IP address of `stackoverflow.com`?".
4. When Cloudflare response with the IP address, your browser will do one of two things: 
   A) it will attempt to directly connect with Cloudflare's IP address, which may not be routable from your internal network. B) Completely bypass the proxy, which was installed to protect the internal network from malicious websites.

Enterprises may have legitimate issues with letting devices not traverse the proxy, content management being just one of them.  Keep in mind that enterprises may enable DoH on the edge of their network so that those queries are encrypted.  But they still want to control the traffic from within their network, which is why enabling DoH at a device/user level is not ideal.

Comment: I don't think this is how it works with the CONNECT method for an HTTP-proxy. I am not sure if DoH can work in this setup at all, because DNS is not done by the computer, but by the proxy server. Not sure if the CONNECT method accepts IP addresses instead of hostnames.

Answer (score -1):

DoH definitely unable to work via proxy, because HTTP(S) proxy protocol is not designed for name resolving on the client side.

A "proxy" is a message-forwarding agent for HTTP (RFC 7230). It just forwards request and responce HTTP messages between user-agent and server.

- [RFC7230 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and
  Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)
- [RFC7231 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1):
  Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)

Comment: can you please add some sources and quotation for your statement? Any RfC or official documentation would be helpful in validating your answer.

Comment: If you claim that "http is not designed for name resolving" I wonder if you understood what DoH is.